# Type text without displaying text

Tags: python, raw-input

I need something like `raw_input`, but without displaying the text you are typing.
Also I tried `getpass`, but it still displays what I just typed.

Comment: You might want to look into using things like `ncurses`.

Comment: Related: [Can i get console input without echo in python?](/q/4616813/4518341)

Answer (score 11):

`getpass` work very well either in command prompt or in python script.

```
import getpass
x = getpass.getpass("Input something: ")
print x
```

Answer (score 2):

`getpass()` doesn't work in IDLE. Try it in command prompt or on the terminal.

Comment: I need something that can do it within the script. So if getpass doesn't work in the IDLE, then I need something else

Comment: Why exactly is this necessary to take an input in the script, but not display it? `getpass()` works very well in every application I can think of, so what exactly are you using this for?